# Pause the azure storage sync service

Tags: azure, azure-storage

How can I pause the Azure Storage Sync Service?
[image]

Comment: What would be the reason you want to do so if you don't mind me asking Avi ?

Answer (score 0):

If you stop the service called `filesyncsvc` , it will stop the sync session.